# Excel and HTML output in same stored Process possible?

Tags: sas

I have a stored Process which returns an Excel as Download (with long loading time because of big data). This works correct, but after download it leaves a blank page. So i want to put some html text in the blank page, best would be a loading icon before, and a "finished" information after downloading the excel. But when i use a ods html after/Before the excel output, instead of downloading the excel it puts the excel as HTML-TextOutput as well, is there a way to do both outputs in one Process?

Code Sample:

```
/* something like:*/

ods html body=_webout; 
data _null_;
file _webout;
put '<img src="loading.gif" />';
run;
ods html close;
/*here is the Exceloutput which i use at the moment without htmloutput*/

%let RV=%sysfunc(appsrv_header(Content-type, application/vnd.ms-excel));
%let RV=%sysfunc(appsrv_header(Content-disposition,%str(attachment; filename=myExcel.xls )));


ods tagsets.excelxp file=_webout options(embedded_titles='yes' embedded_footnotes='yes' 
                     sheet_interval='none' sheet_name='Result') ;

 PROC PRINT DATA=AUSDRUCK UNIFORM NOOBS LABEL; 
 OPTIONS DATE NUMBER; 
 TITLE1"myExcel "; 
 VAR var1 var2 var3 var4 var5; 

 RUN; 

ods tagsets.excelxp close;

/*and then something like:*/

ods html body=_webout; 
data _null_;
file _webout;
put 'Excel download finished successfull';
run;
ods html close;
```

Comment: I have not been able to do this. Looking forward to an answer!

Comment: Away from SAS so can't post a real answer. Suggest this approach from Niko Markovic. https://communities.sas.com/message/208780#208780. In short, the STP writes excel file to disk, then sends html file to webout. The html file is an iframe where the content is a URL that invokes a STP that streams the file to _weboutt with appropriate header. I use this approach for a "please wait" message. Nik's example uses recursive STP but I use two STPs, as I made a utility "stream file" STP where prompt is the file to be streamed.

Comment: Hi Quentin, thank you for your suggestion. At the moment i already work in a frame, and the first Process (some html webout for parameters and information text) already writes the loading icon after submit. Then the next Process writes in same frame and overwrites the loading icon for html and pdf output with the result, which works fine, But i also got some Excel Processes and hoped to avoid a 3th Process for them, But if nobody comes with a better idea, i guess i have to solve it the way you suggested.